# jQuery: Why doesnt the following reassign dollar '$'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variable-assignment

In the following example a user attempts to reassign the dollar function `$` in a developer console with jQuery loaded.

```
[18:39:57.071] $ = function(){"hello"}
[18:39:57.072] (function (){"hello"})
[18:40:00.367] $
[18:40:00.381] (function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    })
```

Why is the dollar function `$` not redefined?

Comment: I tried with the chrome developer console and I don't have the problem you are pointing. Which developer console are you using?

Comment: Thank you polkduran, I'll check and update here when I know.

Comment: Fyi the user hasn't got back to me. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are facing a "scope" problem and you are not redefining the `$` at the "global" scope.

You can try this : `window.$ = function(){"hello";}`

Comment: I guess this must be it. Thank you.